# What difference does it make to have Companion.foo in a companion object?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-companion

In Kotlin, if I have a function in a companion object with `Companion.` as the prefix (`Companion.foo`), what difference will it make compared to a `foo` inside the companion object?

I noticed that in the following code, `Companion.foo` will make it invisible to the outside scope, but still visible to functions inside the same companion object.

You can find the code snippet at: https://pl.kotl.in/t6FvM6ni6

```java
fun main() {
    A.foo() // compiler complains "unresolved reference"
    A.bar()
    B.foo()
}

class A {
    companion object {
        fun Companion.foo() {
            println("hello in A")
        }

        fun bar() {
            foo()
        }
    }
}

class B {
    companion object {
        fun foo() {
            println("hello in B")
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any other differences? Are `A.Companion.foo` and `A.foo` the same apart from the visibility? Is this a way to encapsulate methods in the companion object?

---

Update 1

In my actual project, I'm calling an `inline` function from another `inline` function in the companion object, which is why access modifiers can't be used. But I still would like to hide `foo` if possible.

```java
class C {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> Companion.foo() {
            println("hello in A")
        }

        inline fun bar() {
            foo<String>()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the definition `Companion.foo()` is an [extension as a member](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members). In this case you define the extension in the same type `A.Companion` as the type of the extension. This is not useful.

The next example shows the concept of an extension as member with two different classes. The example is without companions, because  it makes no difference for the concept.

```
class A 

class B {
    fun A.foo() {
        println("Extension for A, only visible in B")
        println("Function has two 'this' references: ${this} and ${this@B}")
    }

    fun bar() {
        val a = A()
        a.foo() // this function call is only possible in the context of `B`
    }
}

fun main() {
    val a = A()
    a.foo() // compile error
}
```

That all said, the two `foo()` function in your example have different  signatures internally. The normal function `foo()` is a simple method on the companion object without parameters. The extension function `Companion.foo()` is a method on the companion object but with an extra parameter for the second `this` reference.

To encapsulate methods within companions, just put the `private` modifier before the function.

If you need an inline function, use `internal` and [`@PublishedApi`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-published-api/index.html) to hide the function from the public API.

```
class C {
    companion object {
        @PublishedApi
        internal inline fun <reified T> foo() {
            println("hello in A")
        }

        inline fun bar() {
            foo<String>()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was using `inline` so `private` is not an option. Please see the updated question description. Would `Companion.foo` be helpful in this case?